# Content Security Policy violation in CORS environment

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, content-security-policy

I have an angular 2 client, a resource server and an authentication server. Everything was running smoothly till I came to screeching  halt this afternoon

here is an image of the error I am getting

[image]

Let me add that I have seen several issues relating to this and have tried almost all the solutions prescribed to no avail

I also have the following class that is suppose to provide me cover from this policy violation

```
 public class SecurityHeadersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result;
        if (result is ViewResult)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Content-Type-Options"))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            }
            if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Frame-Options"))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
            }

            var csp = "default-src 'self'";
            // once for standards compliant browsers
            if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Security-Policy"))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
            }
            // and once again for IE
            if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Content-Security-Policy"))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Security-Policy", csp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It however appears like after upgrading "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" from version 1.1.2 to  1.1.3 my cover has been blown.
How can I get round this challenge?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSP policy needs to allow content from `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com`. So try changing this:

```
var csp = "default-src 'self'";
```

…to this:

```
var csp = "default-src 'self'; style-src https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com"; script-src https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com;
```

But based on the error message cited in the question, it seems the `Content-Security-Policy` header value is getting set already somewhere other than in that part of your application code.

So rather than using `context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add`, which just adds another header, try using`context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set` to override the existing value.

If you do that, you also want to remove `if` condition wrapped around the place you’re setting it.

So try changing this:

```
if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Security-Policy"))
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
}
```

…to just this:

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
```

…so that in the end together you have this:

```
var csp = "default-src 'self'; style-src https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com"; script-src https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com;
context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
```

And if that doesn’t work then you need to find the other place in the backend code where the `Content-Security-Policy` header value is getting set, and change it so the value includes `style-src https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com"; script-src https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I did manage to get rid of the errors with a bit of modification to your suggestion but however I do have another problem: The hyperlinks on the requested page are not working anymore and my post request is also not getting through I get the error code 400. This was a functional application until this content policy problem came up. Hope you can provide m with some guidance here

Comment: That sounds like a different problem so I think you probably want to post a new separate question about that